# What programming language uses a file, a .d and a .k file extension

Tags: unix

I'm looking into some software for my wife who took over a medical practice and the software currently installed on the systems are completely unknown to me.

I can see in the /data directory, that there are 3 files which has some form of relationship to each other:

a (file), without an extension, a .k file and a .d file, for example:

- account
- account.k
- account.d
- etc.

If I open the .k file in Notepad++, it looks something like this:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out what sofware this might be, or at least, the programming language used here, as I need to make a few amendments to the code (all files have either no file extension, a .k, .d, .q or .r extension), so that I can download the appropriate editor to make these. Apparently, the software was bought in 2001, and runs only on a Linux environment.

Comment: Here is related answer https://askubuntu.com/a/7651 I hope this help,
Thanks

Comment: Is it no longer installed alongside the files?

Comment: The [List of filename extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions) may be helpful.  Or use the Linux [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command

Comment: Try `strings account.d` and look for useful info. Or try to find what is installed with `history 1000`, `echo "PATH=${PATH}"` and `cat ~.,profile; cat ~/.bashrc`.